# Prolog max in a list

Tags: prolog

```
mymax([], 'list_is_empty').
mymax([Head | []], Max) :- (Max >= Head).
mymax([Head | List], Max) :- (Max > Head), mymax(List,Max).
```

This seems to work correctly with queries like mymax([1,5,3], 5), etc., but is unable to
find a max value on its own and gives the following error:

```
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I kind of understand why this is the case, though I can't verbalize it.
Can this be fixed or is my algorithm totally incorrect?

Comment: You should probably state explicitly that this predicate looks for the largest _number_ in a list.

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by Max being still unbound when you compare with Head.

You could simplify in this way:

```
mymax([Max], Max).
mymax([Head | List], Max) :-
  mymax(List, MaxList),
  ( Head > MaxList -> Max = Head ; Max = MaxList ).
```

*edit*

I tried to minimize modification to your code, but, as @mat pointed out, that would work only for a list of expressions, for instance, numbers. Then you can write

```
1 ?- mymax([4+1, 3+3], N).
N = 3+3
```

If you are not sure about the list' domain (i.e. the kind of its elements), could be better to use the [term comparison](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28@%3E%29/2) operator:

```
 ( Head @> MaxList -> ... )
```

but now:

```
?- mymax([4+1, 3+3], N).
N = 4+1
```

Comment: I don't understand the operator ->

Comment: Also, can you explain why we need MaxList and what mymax(List, MaxList) does generally?

Comment: (IF -> THEN ; ELSE) [check your favorite Prolog's documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=control)

Comment: Correct answer, as always (+1), but wasn't it so that we shouldn't leave a space around the pipe character: `[Head|Tail]`?

Comment: This yields the same error that OP mentions for a query like: `?- mymax([_,_], Max).`

Comment: @Boris: to be true, I wrote that code without testing... Spaces are *forbidden* after the functor, never heard about operators, or the pipe symbol... But I cannot remember just now what Covington said in his style recommendation.

Comment: Your edited version yields wrong results, for example: `?- mymax([A,B], Max), A = 1, B = 0.` yields: `Max = 0`.

Comment: @mat: you're right, of course, but don't you think it could be confusing for a newbie ? after all, Prolog has its limits... otherwise, I would point him to library predicate max_list/2,aggregate/3 and the like. That have limits themselves...

Comment: If anything, it should be confusing for a newbie that simply exchanging two goals yields different and incorrect results. Just use constraints: They can be used in all directions and have no nasty surprises. Also, the ideal solution for the issue raised by OP: "find max value on its own".

Comment: @mat: again, you're right, but a newbie should *learn* that exchanging two goals it's the *main* control flow 'tool' we have, if not the only. Otherwise, it's not Prolog we're speaking about...

Comment: Correct answer (+1). The only potential problem is that it uses no *tail-recursion*, while the program can easily be transformed to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 2):

Low-level arithmetic operators like `(>=)/2` and `(>)/2` only work when their arguments are instantiated to *concrete* arithmetic expressions.

To make your program work also for more general queries like `?- mymax(List, Max).`, consider using *constraints*, which are available in all major Prolog implementations.

For example, using finite domain constraints in SICStus or SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_max([L|Ls], Max) :-
    list_max_(Ls, L, Max).

list_max_([], Max, Max).
list_max_([L|Ls], Max0, Max) :-
    Max1 #= max(Max0,L),
    list_max_(Ls, Max1, Max).
```

Or equivalently, using `foldl/4`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_max([L|Ls], Max) :- foldl(x_y_max, Ls, L, Max).

x_y_max(X, Y, Max) :- Max #= max(X, Y).
```

Example query and some results:

```
?- list_max(Ls, Max).
Ls = [Max] ;
Ls = [_G551, _G554],
Max#>=_G551,
Max#=max(_G551, _G554),
Max#>=_G554 ;
Ls = [_G636, _G639, _G642],
_G657#>=_G636,
_G657#=max(_G636, _G639),
Max#>=_G657,
_G657#>=_G639,
Max#=max(_G657, _G642),
Max#>=_G642.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it easy, sort, reverse, take the head:

```
mymax(List, Max) :-
    sort(List, Sorted),
    reverse(Sorted, [Max|_]).
```

Otherwise, take the first element and set it to be your largest one (so far). Then look through the rest of the list and if you find an element larger than the current largest, replace your current max with it. This is what @CapelliC is doing (sort of), using an if-then-else control predicate.

One way to do it *without* using an if-then predicate, using predicate clauses instead, and taking advantage of the ISO predicate `compare`:

```
mymax([First|Rest], Max) :-
    mymax_1(Rest, First, Max).
mymax_1([], Max, Max).
mymax_1([This|Rest], Current, Max) :-
    compare(Cmp, This, Current),
    mymax_2(Cmp, Rest, This, Current, Max).
mymax_2(>, Rest, This, _, Max) :-
    mymax_1(Rest, This, Max).
mymax_2(=, Rest, _, Current, Max) :-
    mymax_1(Rest, Current, Max).
mymax_2(<, Rest, _, Current, Max) :-
    mymax_1(Rest, Current, Max).
```

But this style of writing predicates is not very popular, probably because it is too explicit and involves typing too much. On the other hand, it is tail-recursive and deterministic. It also doesn't break when you pass a variable as the first argument:

```
?- mymax(L, 13).
```

You can also look at the implementation of `max_list/2` and `max_member/2` from the standard library of any open-source Prolog implementation ([SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src) for example) for a more pragmatic approach (but still using if-then-else).

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum of a list you can say that it's a member of this list, and there is no element of this list greater than it :

```
my_max(L, V) :-
    member(V, L),
    \+((member(X, L), X > V)).
```

Comment: Isn't the problem with this approach that your program will have a *O(n^2)* time complexity? Whereas using an accumulator, would result in *O(n)* time complexity.

Comment: I agree, it's a problem, but with Prolog, I think that one must "think different" !

Comment: No that's with Apple. You don't buy a *Mac*, A *Mac* sells you... :P